# how to pass the output of a node as a property-variable to next node, in Data Fusion Studio

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

QS 1: How to read a configuration table/file which contain basic properties of a nodes {ex: source and sink table names etc.} and use that output in the next nodes in FUSION pipeline.

tried to use the Remote Program Executor, with command as -

```
bq query --format csv 'select SOURCE_TABLE,TASK_ID,DELTA_DATE from FUSIONDATASET.TEST_CONFIG where RUN_STATUS=0'
```

Now how to use this output in the nest pipeline nodes,say the SOURCE_TABLE col, in the source bigQuery node's TABLE property

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action plugin to set runtime arguments that can be used in any subsequent stages in a pipeline.

As an example you can refer to argument setter plugin that reads a set of configurations and sets these are runtime arguments. https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter/

Specifically the line here https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter/blob/develop/src/main/java/io/cdap/plugin/ArgumentSetter.java#L77 sets up key and value of the runtime argument.